# How to document a primary constructor parameter with Kotlin Dokka

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-dokka

Let's say there's a class which primary constructor has the parameter `param` that I'd like to be resolved (linked to the actual parameter) within the doc block of the class.

```
/** Class A does something using [param]. 
@constructor constructs A with [param].
*/
class A (param: Int)
```

However, the inscription `param` is highlighted by the IDE saying that it cannot resolve symbol `param`.

Comment: Interesting. This works fine, except for the IDE warning. If I add a `val` or `var` before `param` it goes away (and of course becomes a property) - and I don't get the warning if I document a method param in this way.

Comment: @AdamS That's how it's meant to work for properties and method params. I could add a `constructor` identifier before the primary constructor and treat it as a method. But I'd like to avoid clutter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, dokka correctly finds the parameter if you reference it with `[param]` in the `@constructor` paragraph, you can check that by inspecting the URL that appears in the assembled docs, which looks like:

```
file:///.../some.package/-a/-init-.html#some.package.A$<init>(kotlin.Int)/param
```

Seemingly, the warning about an unresolved reference is an issue with the IDE support for KDoc. Please report it at [kotl.in/issue](http://kotl.in/issue).

Another option is to use `@param` in the class KDoc:

```
/** 
 * Class A does something using [param]. 
 * @param param means something special.
*/
class A (param: Int)
```